# PowerShell: Why is Get-Unique only returning the first object from a collection?

Tags: powershell

I have a series of JSON files structured as follows:

```json
{
  "start": "B",
  "end": "D",
  "display": true
}
```

The contents of which are:

| File | `start` | `end` | `display` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | C | True |
| 2 | B | C | True |
| 3 | B | D | True |
| 4 | A | B | True |
| 5 | A | C | True |
| 6 | A | B | True |

The files are parsed in PowerShell like so:

```
$edges = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.json" `
    | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object @{n="start";e={$_.start}},@{n="end";e={$_.end}},@{n="display";e={$_.display}} }

# start end display
# ----- --- -------
# B     C      True
# B     C      True
# B     D      True
# A     B      True
# A     C      True
# A     B      True
```

I now want to filter the collection to only contain unique values; ordering is not important in my scenario:

```
# Desired Output
#
# start end display
# ----- --- -------
# B     C      True
# B     D      True
# A     B      True
# A     C      True
```

By my interpretation of the official documentation, I should [sort the collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.1) before calling [`Get-Unique`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique?view=powershell-7.1):

```
$edges = $edges `
    | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = "start"; Descending = $False}, @{Expression = "end"; Descending = $False} `
    | Get-Unique
```

However, regardless of whether the collection is sorted or not, `Get-Unique` only returns the first item:

```
# Unsorted:
#
# start end display
# ----- --- -------
# B     C      True

# Sorted:
#
# start end display
# ----- --- -------
# A     B      True
```

Have I misunderstood how `Get-Unique` works? How can the intended output be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try -unique in select-object

```
$edges = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.json" | 
            ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object @{n="start";e={$_.start}},@{n="end";e={$_.end}},@{n="display";e={$_.display}} } | select * -Unique
```

you can simplify your code like this :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\tmp" -Filter "*.json" | %{

Get-Content $_.FullName | ConvertFrom-Json

} | select * -Unique
```

Comment: try my modification

Answer (score 8):

[Get-Unique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique?view=powershell-5.1) has two parameter sets. One uses the `-AsString` parameter and one uses the `-OnType` parameter. When a collection of custom objects is piped into `Get-Unique`, the `-OnType` parameter is used. Therefore it outputs only one object of each type. If you explicitly use the `-AsString` parameter, you will get the expected results.

```
# json
$json = @'
[{
  "start": "B",
  "end": "D",
  "display": true
},
{
  "start": "B",
  "end": "D",
  "display": true
},
{
  "start": "A",
  "end": "F",
  "display": false
},{
  "start": "A",
  "end": "F",
  "display": false
}
]
'@

($json | ConvertFrom-Json) | Sort-Object start,end,display | Get-Unique -AsString
```

**Output:**

```
start end display
----- --- -------
A     F     False
B     D      True
```

Note that `Get-Unique` is case-sensitive when comparing strings.

Comment: This was extremely helpful for me! I had a situation when fetching PSCustomObjects from a REST call where I needed to ensure that the user only was shown unique entries and couldn't figure out why piping to Select-Object -Unique would only give me the first PSCustomObject every time. -AsString made it work as expected. Thank you very much!